# What's the difference between kafka partition and kafka connect partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm new to Kafka Connect, I don’t know the difference between kafka partition and kafka connect partition. Are they the same concept? If they are not the same concept, what is the relationship between them?

Here is introduction document for kafka connect partition: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Connect doesn't have partitions, only workers and tasks. All tasks are wrappers around Producer and Consumer APIs which read and write from topic partitions. The documentation refers to "Stream partitions", but that's actually "Kafka topic"

The [JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceRecord.html) of a SourceRecord explains what the internal partition values actually mean, "filename, table name, **or topic-partition**", but the value itself is arbitrary and connector dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have doubts about "partition". Here is the api document of kafka connect:https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceRecord.html 
What’s the meaning of "sourcePartition" and "souceOffset" in the document?

Comment: That is just the parameter name and doesn't really relate to Kafka broker values.. It explains it exactly there - **e.g. a filename, table name, _or topic-partition_**. So, the JDBC source, for example, uses a id/timestamp column value for an "offset" and the table itself for a "source partition" that the Connector reads from. The S3 source would use a bucket prefix for the "sourcePartition", and a line-number for an "offset" within that "partition" (i.e. file)

Comment: Based on your answer, can I think that **sourcePartion** is only used to represent the real meaning of the data, it's just a name, and **sourcePartion** has no relationship with kafka topic partition?

Comment: MirrorMaker is a source connector. It needs to read from Kafka topic partitions, but that's really the only example where that's 1:1 mapping